# Paragraph not moving using left-margin

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move every single paragraph by 10 pixels from left using CSS by assigning a left margin of `10px` to p. However, they don't seem to be updating

CSS:

```css
.container {
  width: 680px;
  height: 900px;
  background-image: url("images/bgcontainer.jpg");
  overflow: auto;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  }

p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

HTML of paragraphs I'm trying to move:

```html
<p align="left">
  <h5 align="left" width="650px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
    <a href="">exercitation ullamco</a>
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea.
  </h5>
</p>
```

I just want the assigned property of the paragraph written in CSS to be applied and actually move the paragraphs.

Comment: The <p> tag can only contain inline elements. The header tags are block-level elements, and cannot go inside <p> tags even when you style them to display inline. so You should separate the paragraph, <p></p> from the heading, <h1></h1> element or use div instead of p element.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the h5 tag inside of the p tag.
Like this it would be invalid HTML anyways.
Structure could be like:

```html
<h1>Headline</h1>
<h2>Subheadline</h2>
<p>Some lorem stuff</p>
<h3>Subsubheadline</h3>
<p>More lorem stuff</p>
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is invalid. Using a heading element inside a paragraph element is impossible. Because the browser will automatically close the `p` element when it 'sees' a `heading` tag like `<h5>` so your html is invalid.

Never nest a heading inside a paragraph.

Second, `align` is not supported in HTML5. Use css instead or inline styles.

using just a p element ( without a nesting h5 ) will work as intended. See below

```css
  p {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a href="">exercitation ullamco</a> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea.</p>
```

To explain more. Your HTML code will be interpreted by the browser like this

`<p></p><h5>heading here<a>link</a></h5></p>` Notice that the p is closed before the starting of the `h5`. So that's why the 'margin-left' doesn't have any effect. Plus you end up with an extra `</p>` closing tag